# Halcon - extract crate region

Tags: extract, region, halcon

I'm having huge difficulties to extract the region of the black crate from this image.

My situation is this:
the blue is a region that i have predefined as it is roughly where the crate has to be. I use it to reduce the domain of the image.
The yellow is the result i need: a filled region of the crate itself, as precise as possible.
I managed to extract the crate with the Saturation channel, but it includes too much from above the crate..

I tried R G B and H L S channels, combinig them between each other, but without success.. unfortunately I was not able to find a combination that extracts the crate reliably.

ATTENTION: in this picture there is the Blue crate behind.. but there can be any other crate. Also the black crate in front can have any height. I already sorted the situations where the front crate is blue or green, but for the black it is getting quite difficult...

Here is a Image with a low crate height...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think that it’s the right manner.
I think it’s better to avoid the conveyor belt and the window where you can see the other basket.
In a few words, you can use 2 domains: left and right.
In every domain, you can search for the basket part and then detect the line borders (left, top1, top2, right).
When you know these four lines (really only one top segment it’s necessary) you know where is the basket and you can reconstruct its region.

[image]

Comment: Thank you vor your answer. In general I'd agree with you, your solution is better and easier, but it presents a new challenge.. In some cases, the front wall is closed. I need to detect that.. I detect that by drawing a line below where you have the "top1" line, and counting the intersections with the region. With this solution, that would not work anymore. Also, there are crates with only 10 cm in height, those would fall completely int he belt section...

Comment: Hi, the crate color is almost gray, so I don't think that color transformation can help you.

Comment: Maybe you can use a filter like emphasize

Comment: Can you post a photo with a low height crate?

Comment: Thanks.. looking into emphasize... and added a picture of a low crate..

Comment: The low crate is not into the belt section. So you can use my suggested method to find the real cate size (you can think to this as a domain). After you can do the intersection between the region you find (maybe using emphasize) and the real cate size. In this manner, you'll remove/reduce the influence of the crate that is behind.